# Pressure Drop in a Pipe due to Pressure Increase

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, flow, thermal-conductivity

I'm trying to calculate the pressure/temperature change in a pipe due to heating. Basically, assume there's a pipe, the pipe wall is at an increased temperature, how to calculate the pressure, temperature, and density over the length of the pipe. The mass flow rate, temperature/pressure/density in are known values.

I understand how to calculate the temperature change, as this is a simple heat transfer problem. However, pressure/density calculation doesn't seem to be something obvious. I read another post discussing that the pressure in the pipe will remain constant, but density will change. Is this valid? How is this possible?

Any assistance would be truly appreciated!

Comment: What fluid is in a pipe? Also it is not clear how temperature of pipe increases with time. Is there temperature gradient along of pipe?

Comment: Oh yeah?  What is your understanding of how to determine the temperature change?  Is the flow turbulent or laminar?  Is the fluid compressible?  What do you think the parameters of the fluid are that are needed to answer this?  What are your thoughts so far on how to approach this?